# Trouble getting the last bit when reading output from process

Tags: c#, process, console, readline

I am building a small program to help me when I use a server console for a game (hence I do not have the source for the console program).
I have the console starting up in the background and it redirects the output and I then write it in cute little textbox.
Problem is that It doesn't seem to give me the last line every time it makes an output.
This is some code from my server.cs:

```
public StreamWriter inputWriter;
public event EventHandler outputWritten;

string outtext = outputReader.ReadLine();

        while (!process.HasExited)
        {
            // check for output from server
            if (outtext != null)
            {
                if (outputWritten != null)
                {
                    outputWritten(outtext, new EventArgs());
                }
            }
            outtext = outputReader.ReadLine();
        }
```

This is pretty much what the output would look like:
1) If it would run outside my program:

```
Welcome to the game server!
1  OptionA
2  OptionB
3  OptionC

Choose option:_  <-- this is where it should end waiting for input
```

2) If inside my program:
It would look like the above but wouldn't show the last line in stead it would end right at the empty line above the "Choose option:"
And when I give it an input it messes it up a bit and I get an output looking like "Choose option: Welcome to the game server!" where it should have written: "Choose option: 1" and on the next line given my a small question on how to proceed.

Comment: Its waiting because you asked it to read a line, not just read text. If you change it to read not readline, you may have to do more processing, but it allows for partial lines.

Comment: it reads every line by itself as it is.. it just messes up when it gets to the last line each time there is something new to read.. I watched it go through the reading using breakpoints and it sends each line fine till it has send the last empty line right before "choose option" and it just seems to stop reading? seems weird to me at least..